# react native how can I make flatlist with dynamic width

Tags: react-native, expo

how can I make flatlist with dynamics width like insta ?

I can make it with flatlist numOfColumns but the images are not between each other like instagram.[image]

Comment: could you add a screenshot of the example from Instagram you mention? They both use lists, grids and carousels :-)

Comment: @SimonDegn yes of course, i added a picture

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `react-native-layout-grid`. It seems like it could do the job for you with columns and adjustable sizes.

https://github.com/toystars/react-native-layout-grid#readme

Comment: I know how I set 3 items next to but if you use image,  you have to set a width and height else the image will not show. So how can I use now dynamics images

Comment: Just place the image inside the rendered items and set width and height to '100%' like this:  <Image resizeMode="cover" style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} source={{uri: "... image_url ... }} />

Comment: They use listview, so can I do it with flatlist because of the performance ?

Comment: You will get the same result with flatlists.